# A possible bug in NSSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, text-to-speech

I am writing an OS X application which uses `NSSpeechSynthesizer` to read text to the user and highlights the word it is reading in the text field (`NSTextView`). This is done by implementing the `speechSynthesizer:willSpeakWord:ofString:` method of the `NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` protocol. This method provides the range (`NSRange`) of the word it is about to speak which I forward to the setSelectedRange method of my `NSTextView`.

All is well until I stop the reading with the `stopSpeaking` method. If I set it to read again after this, the ranges provided by `speechSynthesizer:willSpeakWord:ofString:` seem to be out of sync. It seems that it hesitates calling `speechSynthesizer:willSpeakWord:ofString:` for a few seconds resulting in the ranges being somewhat behind the speech when it finally does.

I have written a simple application illustrating the issue, which can be found here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12516679/SpeechTest.zip

I hope that someone will look at this code (it really is simple) and either confirm that this indeed seems to be a bug, or (hopefully) tell me what I am doing wrong.

**- UPDATE -**

It turns out that the problem occurs with non-english voices. I was originally using Ida, which is a Danish voice. I have now tested it with many different voices and I can confirm that it works well with all English voices. However it fell out of sync with Danish, Swedish, Norwegian and Dutch. It probably affects other languages as well, but these are the ones I have tested so far.

Comment: Your speech application seems to be working fine, at least on my computer. Could you describe your problem in a bit more detail? Because from my point of view everything is working fine, even when I invoke the "stopSpeaking" method, and press play. The sync appears to be working fine.

Comment: Working fine for me too... What version of OS X are you on?

Comment: Well, I guess that is good news. Perhaps there is hope for me too :) My problem is that after the reading has been stopped and I press play again the synthesizer starts speaking right away. However, the first call to "speechSynthesizer:willSpeakWord:ofString:" seems to come a few seconds late resulting in the highlighting being out of sync. And the ranges I print out using NSLog are wrong as well.
I have a new 15” MBP running Lion. We have tested the application on a colleague’s brand new iMac (also running Lion) and it has the same issue.

Comment: There is an update on the issue. Please read above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the source of the problem and a workaround. It has nothing to do with the language as such, but the fact that most non-English voices in OS X Lion are Nuance voices (made by Nuance Communications). I have confirmed this by testing with English Nuance voices and they indeed have the same problem. It looks like there is something wrong in the api for voices provided by Nuance.
I have created a workaround for the problem by instantiating a new `NSSpeechSynthesizer` object after the reading has been stopped. It’s not pretty but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug, but it has been solved in the update of the Nuance voices for Mountain Lion.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I submitted a bug report to Apple just under a year ago, and a few weeks later I got a reply that it would be fixed in Mountain Lion. However, I still needed a workaround since 1) our application was released before Mountain Lion and 2) it needed to work with Lion as well.